# Apache/PHP add handler will not work for PHP5

Tags: php, apache, addhandler

My clients host uses PHP4 and 5 and all *.php files run via 5 but when I use this

> <FilesMatch "edit.js">
>     AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
>   </FilesMatch>

it runs as PHP 4.4.9 but not on my personal web server (VPS) I need this file.

> <FilesMatch "edit.js">
>     AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .js
>   </FilesMatch>

doesn't seem to work just displays source code of PHP.

and help appreciated.

Comment: With what specifically you need help (a.k.a. what is your question)?

Comment: Why are you trying to add a handler for this file? Usually one would have a php file and use mod_rewrite to redirect `edit.js` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .js
                                  ^---
```

Since, as you say, your host has both PHP 4 and PHP 5, you need to expclitly say which version you want used.

Comment: Well, which apache handler is configured for `application/x-httpd-php5`? You need to mimic the webservers configuration on your localhost to get the same behaviour.