# How to make .php extension not appear on website?

Tags: php

I am using PHP for my website, and `.php` is appearing in my URLs. How can I remove this?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of ways you could achieve this, but they depend largely on your choice of web server.

If, for instance, you were using Apache HTTPD you could use:

- [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) *or*
- [AddHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872759/apache-php-add-handler-will-not-work-for-php5) (e.g. inside [Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) or [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch)) *or*
- [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) *or*
- [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

… other options are probably available, but those are the ones that spring to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called .htaccess ( the dot in .htaccess is not an accident ) and enter the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L,QSA]
```

Then save the file and place it a the root directory of your website.

Comment: what do i do if i have .html extension?  I tried to change the .php to .html but its not working.

Comment: Try this in your .htaccess file
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php